# adding string as name of set to a map

Tags: java, string, dictionary, set

I thought this would be easy but I am struggling...I want to send 2 Strings to a method and have one as the map key and the other as the name of the set;
Edit: Map declaration;
Edit 2 to add constructor for map;

```
public HashMap<String, Set<String>> playerMap; //edit 1

public Planets()
```

{
      playerMap = new HashMap<>();

} //edit 2

```
public void addMapEntry(String newPlayerAdd, String newPlanetAdd)

{
  playerMap.put(newPlayerAdd, newPlanetAdd);
}
```

and am getting error message

> Argument mismatch
>   java.util.Map.put(java.lang.String,jaav.util.Set) is
>   not applicable; (....) cannot be converted to (...).

I have created the map and previous sets in this same class and all have been added fine...

I have changed the code to

```
 public void addMapEntry(String newPlayerAdd, Set<String> newPlanetAdd) {
  planetStats = new TreeSet<>(newPlanetAdd);
  playerMap.put(newPlayerAdd, newPlanetAdd);
}
```

And am getting a runtime error of the same type instead of a compile time error;
I feel I am not passing the variable in the correct format to the method...any help appreciated...
currently sending in the form of

```
allPlanets.addMapEntry("Jane", "Klethron");
```

Comment: A String is just a String, even if it happens to contain a variable's name. That means you can't use it as a substitute for the actual variable you need to use. If you're trying to add a Set to your Map, you need to add the Set, not a String containing its variable name.

Comment: can you edit your question with playerMap declaration?

Comment: What happens if you remove "planetStats = new TreeSet<>(newPlanetAdd);" - this line from your second code. Also please include declaration of "playerMap"

Comment: edited to add declaration

Comment: edited again to add constructor

Comment: @ Kartic I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your map as

```
Map<String, Set<String>> playerMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>()
```

in case you want to use HashMap implementation.. and should call the method as

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("Klethron");
allPlanets.addMapEntry("Jane", set);
```

Comment: `HashSet.add` does not return `this` but a boolean. Also, that's probably not what OP wanted (not sure _what_ that is, though).

Comment: Tried stack overflow editor..instead of eclipse..but failed to find the boolean value :)

Comment: @ tobias...Just need to add key and value to map from the given arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your Map as

```
Map<String, Set<String>> playerMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>()
```

Initialize your Set

```
Set<String> setString = new HashSet<String>();
setString.add("String1"); //fill up the string set in this way
allPlanets.addMapEntry("Jane", setString);
```